# persistence.xml not found when deploying EAR into OpenEJB with Arquillian

Tags: jakarta-ee, ear, jboss-arquillian, persistence.xml, openejb

I'm trying to run an integration test with Arquillian using OpenEJB embedded as environment, but the deployment fails due to missing persistence.xml.

This is being run in a module ("services") of a multi-module maven project. The module is being deployed as EJB-Jar ("services.jar") in an EAR ("services-ear.ear"). Also in the EAR I include as library the jar("data-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar") of another module of my project ("data"). The latter module holds entity pojos and DAOs as EJBs. The DAOs all have an EntityManager, which references a persistence unit that is declared in the /META-INF/persistence.xml in the "data-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar". So, the structure in the EAR is:

```
ear
|- services.jar
|- /lib/data-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
|- ...
```

The structure gets printed when I build the ear for deployment to verify that these components are really in the archive.
When I run the integration tests, OpenEJB comes up ("15:45:48.345 [LogStreamAsync.Thread] INFO  OpenEJB.server - Ready!") and the archives are built and deployed. OpenEJB finds the EJBs in the "data-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" and starts deploying them. However, it then fails to find the persistence.xml in the same jar. I have verified that the persistence.xml is in the jar. The messages I get are the same for each EJB:

```
...
15:56:42.167 [LogStreamAsync.Thread] ERROR OpenEJB.startup.validation - FAIL ... PlatformDaoImpl:   A persistence unit must be defined via META-INF/persistence.xml to satisfy @PersistenceContext ref "manager" to unit "".  An example of a suitable persistence.xml might be:<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0"><persistence-unit name=""><jta-data-source>java:openejb/Resource/myDataSource</jta-data-source><non-jta-data-source>java:openejb/Resource/myUnmanagedDataSource</non-jta-data-source><properties><property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/></properties></persistence-unit></persistence>
15:56:42.167 [LogStreamAsync.Thread] ERROR OpenEJB.startup.validation - FAIL ... DefaultThreatResponseStatusDaoImpl:    A persistence unit must be defined via META-INF/persistence.xml to satisfy @PersistenceContext ref "manager" to unit "".  An example of a suitable persistence.xml might be:<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0"><persistence-unit name=""><jta-data-source>java:openejb/Resource/myDataSource</jta-data-source><non-jta-data-source>java:openejb/Resource/myUnmanagedDataSource</non-jta-data-source><properties><property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/></properties></persistence-unit></persistence>
15:56:42.167 [LogStreamAsync.Thread] ERROR OpenEJB.startup.validation - FAIL ... DataSourceDaoImpl: A persistence unit must be defined via META-INF/persistence.xml to satisfy @PersistenceContext ref "manager" to unit "".  An example of a suitable persistence.xml might be:<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0"><persistence-unit name=""><jta-data-source>java:openejb/Resource/myDataSource</jta-data-source><non-jta-data-source>java:openejb/Resource/myUnmanagedDataSource</non-jta-data-source><properties><property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/></properties></persistence-unit></persistence>
15:56:42.167 [LogStreamAsync.Thread] ERROR OpenEJB.startup.validation - FAIL ... TechnologyDaoImpl: A persistence unit must be defined via META-INF/persistence.xml to satisfy @PersistenceContext ref "manager" to unit "".  An example of a suitable persistence.xml might be:<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0"><persistence-unit name=""><jta-data-source>java:openejb/Resource/myDataSource</jta-data-source><non-jta-data-source>java:openejb/Resource/myUnmanagedDataSource</non-jta-data-source><properties><property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/></properties></persistence-unit></persistence>
15:56:42.167 [LogStreamAsync.Thread] ERROR OpenEJB.startup.validation - FAIL ... ear-scoped-cdi-beans_services-ear: A persistence unit must be defined via META-INF/persistence.xml to satisfy @PersistenceContext ref "manager" to unit "".  An example of a suitable persistence.xml might be:<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0"><persistence-unit name=""><jta-data-source>java:openejb/Resource/myDataSource</jta-data-source><non-jta-data-source>java:openejb/Resource/myUnmanagedDataSource</non-jta-data-source><properties><property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/></properties></persistence-unit></persistence>
15:56:42.167 [LogStreamAsync.Thread] ERROR OpenEJB.startup.validation - Invalid EjbModule(name=ear-scoped-cdi-beans_services-ear, path=ear-scoped-cdi-beans_services-ear)
...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue?

Comment: I have been able to work around it by including the ejb jars in the web archives. Unfortunately, that also "duplicates" them inside the ear, but without any negative effects so far.